# Error when i tried to install composer with PHP 7 using xampp package

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

when i tried to install composer with php 5.6.3 that return message said i have to install php 5.6.4 at least
so i just download xampp package that support php 7 to be able to install composer and laravel and when i tried to install composer after that the composer show me that Error :

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly [exit code 1]:
E:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: E:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Comment: I'd start with a fresh install.

Comment: Have you checked the extension_dir parameter in the `\xamp\php\php.ini` file

Comment: No i didn't check that What should i do with that @RiggsFolly

Comment: Check that it is correctly pointing to the folder containing the PHP extensions normally `\xamp\php\ext` I think

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Try install Xampp 5.6.24 / PHP 5.6.24 (Not the latest Xampp 7.0.9 / PHP 7.0.9)

Comment: Can you please give a link to download it

Comment: cause every time i download it it just download xampp with php version less than 5.6.2